# For Loop in SQL?

Tags: sql, case

I have a table with ID and corresponding picture count. I want to get the count of ID's based on picture count <200 separated by 1's and for count of ID's based on picture count > 200 separated by 100's.

Is there any way I can do this except case statement? Something like For loop in SQL?

Comment: Is it MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? Something else? Anyway, I would say you don't need a loop at all. You can to that using just SQL query.

Comment: Is this [homework]? Sounds like an odd problem.

Comment: You can do looping in procedures. If this is homework, what did you just learn in class? If is was procedures, that's probably what you need to use :)

Comment: Possible via UNION. OUTER APPLY. JOIN. Via Stored proc and functions. Via CLR assembly. Via linked server.

Comment: What do you mean separated by 1's or by 100's?

Comment: @jim What reason would you have to think that the OP is looking for a Microsoft based answer?  A prior comment already reminds us that there are other databases in the world, and there are even other operating systems.

Comment: @WarrenT i gave correct answer for MS SQL. He didnt specify that condition :)

Comment: @jim a) why give an answer that may be unusable by platform or experience level, b) why give an answer that will require many more lines of code than a plain SQL query?  Occam's razor often prevents a great deal of debugging.

Comment: separated by 1's means : count(id) group by picture count 1 , count(id) group by picture count 2 etc.. grouping the ids by incremental picture count (either 1's or 100's)

Comment: @WarrenT I dont have to guess what platform OP's using, it's his duty as well as providing details. I'm also not always worrying of experience level - just give an answer. It was correct for the specific task and should force OP to provide details next time. I have no idea why not using CASE that's why gave other possible ways.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need any loop at all. You can use `GROUP BY` and do it in two queries:

```
SELECT
FLOOR(pictures / 10) * 10 as `from`,
FLOOR(pictures / 10) * 10 + 9 as `to`,
count(*)
FROM Test
WHERE pictures < 100
GROUP BY FLOOR(pictures / 10);
```

```
SELECT
FLOOR(pictures / 100) * 100 as `from`,
FLOOR(pictures / 100) * 100 + 99 as `to`,
count(*)
FROM Test
WHERE pictures >= 100
GROUP BY FLOOR(pictures / 100);
```

Or combine results into one result set using `UNION ALL`:

```
    (SELECT
    FLOOR(pictures / 10) * 10 as `from`,
    FLOOR(pictures / 10) * 10 + 9 as `to`,
    count(*)
    FROM Test
    WHERE pictures < 100
    GROUP BY FLOOR(pictures / 10))
UNION ALL
    (SELECT
    FLOOR(pictures / 100) * 100 as `from`,
    FLOOR(pictures / 100) * 100 + 99 as `to`,
    count(*)
    FROM Test
    WHERE pictures >= 100
    GROUP BY FLOOR(pictures / 100));
```

See a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dd8a/12